# Signal noise cancelled by touching the leads

Tags: sensor, noise, signal-to-noise

I have a pressure sensor that outputs 0.5V with a +/- 20 mV noise.  I am trying to identify the root cause of the noise using an oscilloscope.
The noise occurs in waves of twice the mains frequency, and each noise wave pulse is made of smaller pulses of much higher fequency.

The noise used to be much higher when I was using a "wall wart" 12V power supply to the sensor than when I used the bench top power supply or a proper 12 V dedicated power supply.

Weird clue 1)  although the noise was partially related to the power supply used, the power output of the wall wart supply didnt show any noise.EDIT: the noise is there, but catching a 50mV noise on a 12V signal was just difficult on my oscilloscope.

Weird clue 2) when I touch with my finger the conductive probes (either positive or negative) of the oscilloscope, while measuring the sensor signal, the noise *decreases*

I got minor improvement in the noise by putting capacitors between the signal and the ground, but I have a feeling my main issue is elsewhere. Can you please clarify the root cause of the noise ?

Edit: after suggestions, please find the oscillo screen using different power supplies[image]

Comment: It's "correlated noise" if you can identify a specific frequency. In this case, it's correlated to your mains frequency (probably doubled because of a bridge rectifier.) It's also likely that the non-linear behavior of these diodes in the bridge rectifier, as they very rapidly flood with current during a short period each half-cycle, is a source of the higher frequency pulses you also observe. There may be other sources, but those are the first two I'd concentrate on. Wall warts are known to be horrible on these aspects, too. So no surprise there.

Comment: Try to use other 12V supply such as batteries which gives clean DC and then observe.

Comment: @jonk yeah but I  dont understand why I dont see the noise on the power output of the power supplies. And  only see it on the sensor output. It's like the noise is transmitted to the sensor in a way that cant be detected by the oscilloscope. Could it be related to different type of grounding/earth issues between the supplies ?

Comment: @Unknown123 great idea, I will.

Comment: @ManudeHanoi If the power supply is unloaded, the capacitors just charge up and sit there. Put a significant resistor load on the power supply and check again.

Comment: @jonk The sensor doesnt use much power and power supply was measured while under the sensor load

Comment: Your overall layout and method of wiring and CM noise can be rectified by unbalanced cables and thus double frequency of AC E fields

Comment: We can't see what you saw, so it is hard to say more. But you measured nothing when using zero load. Zero isn't the same as "not much power." Apply the same load using a resistor and then check. Don't assume.

Comment: CM noise exists but not shown on a schematic. You must show everything for help and read Henry Ott's book on EMC from archive.org

Comment: @jonk I probed the power supply output while it was suppling the sensor with power and saw no noise on the power supply output (but got noise on the sensor output). The power supply is dedicated to the sensor anyways, so I dont need to increase the load.

Comment: Your high impedance amplifier is unbalanced somewhere and is picking up stray E-fields from somewhere, show your work

Comment: Your power supplies have primary-secondary transformers. The diode rectifier fast-edges couple from secondary to primary, and then to every power outlet, and to Ground, of your entire lab and environment. All possible paths back to the diodes is taken by the electrons, including thru you.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I would show a pic if I though it was informative. I dont use amplifier, if there is one it's included in the sensor.

Comment: Well then show it, that is your amplifier.. show everything

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 if you must insist
https://imgur.com/a/F3TeNeh
I've probed on straight on the sensor (without lengthy wires) for the same result

Comment: @analogsystemsrf is there a way to test your hypothesis and to prevent the noise ?

Comment: Do you know how to measure ground noise or make dual probe A-B measurements. The problem is in your setup with a floating ground.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I dont

Comment: You seems to be confused. Seriously, the easiest way to figure it first is using clean DC source. So you can have a certainty that the AC-DC SMPS supply is the main culprit or not and thus may also factor it out or in. You don't tell us your current demands, so I could say that you could put 8 AAA batteries in series or using one 12V lead-acid battery.

Comment: @ all i added a pic with the oscillo readings for the various power supplies including the battery. Indeed the battery removes a lot of noise.
How can power my sensor (I cant use battery ) ?

Comment: Try put LC Low Pass Filter near your power input and also at the sensor output. Also, mentioning @all isn't going to notify everybody, it won't sent into their inbox.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75

Comment: @Unknown123 I 've made a mistake, there was some noise on the power output, it was just a hard to see the 50mv noise on the 12V power. A capacitance from the DC output to the table kills all the 50hz noise

Comment: Next time you're looking for noise on top of a DC signal, just switch your scope to the AC mode. That'll block the 12V DC and only measure the ripple.

Comment: So, is your problem fixed?

Comment: @Unknown123 yes

Comment: I miss a situational picture :) Show us the wires you use, how do you measure with the probes? With the longue return lead, or short?

Comment: And can you explain your solution, a cap from DC to the “table”. I don’t understand the last word.

Answer (score 3):

If a conductor is coupled to mains power through a very small capacitor, then within that conductor the noise appears to have a high source impedance. If a conductor with noise with a high source impedance is coupled to ground through a "low" (relatively speaking) impedance, such as a *larger* capacitor, then the two impedances will form an attenuator or voltage divider.

The fact that the noise in your case becomes significantly attenuated when you touch the leads, or attach capacitors to ground tells me that in your case, the noise does indeed have a high source impedance. It could be caused by capacitance in the windings of the transformer or inductor of your power supply. It could be caused by intentionally added capacitors in your power supply. Often such capacitors are added to eliminate one kind of noise, (often required by law or regulation) but have the side effect of facilitating another kind of noise (the noise you are seeing). Or the noise could be coupled to your circuit through some other "stray" capacitance.

Answer (score 0):

A capacitance from the DC output to the table kills all the 50hz noise